# Failed to load content css: //www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css

Tags: tinymce

I have suddenly started getting this error. I use this an open source application.  Have this problem in both Chrome & Edge.

```
Failed to load content css: //www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css
```

Once I remove this window, I can use the editor normally.

I gather that this file is on the cloud.

Can anyone help to remove this bug.

Thanks in advance

Natraj

Answer (score 0):

use this https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js
and this for css: https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
good luck